# Java slideshow without using ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, slideshow

It's my first question there so please don't be so cruel .

I've got problem with my program , it means i don't know why i have got NullpointerException , anybody knows why ?

My code : `package ex2;

```
public class Screen extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image ; 
    private Timer tm ; 
    private Graphics g ;
    private static int index = 0 ; 
    private ArrayList<String> paths = new Test().getArrayList();
    public Screen(){
        System.out.println(paths);
        String interval  ; 
        interval = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please write time interval "
                + "between images in miliseconds");
        tm = new Timer(Integer.parseInt(interval), new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    paint(index);
                    index += 1 ;
                    if (index >= paths.size())
                        System.exit(index);     
                } catch (IOException e1) {                  
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }                                               
            }
        });
        tm.start();
    }
    public void paint(int i) throws IOException{
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(paths.get(i)));
        g.drawImage(image, 40, 30, image.getWidth() , image.getHeight() , null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The very least you could do would be pointing out which line causes the NPE. However you are not initializing `g` anywhere in this code, so there's your most likely cause

Comment: Including your error and stack trace would go a long way towards helping you.

Comment: You should take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works and how you can worlk with the system to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Graphics g ;
```

Looks null to me.

If you want to do custom painting then you need to override the `paintComponent()` method of your `JPanel` and use the Graphics object that is passed to the method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples that show the proper way to do painting.

> Java slideshow without using ImageIcon

Why are you trying to do this without an `ImageIcon`? Why reinvent the wheel?

Just read the Image and create an `ImageIcon` and add the icon to a `JLabel` and the label to the frame. Then you change the image using the `setIcon(...)` method. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Icons` to get you started.

Comment: I'm sorry that I answer today , this is my task at school , I've made this aplication with ImageIcon but there is requirment to do this without ImageIcon , ok I've got not null and program show my image but just one .